# How to read Connection String from a Config file?

Tags: c#

I wanted to develop an App which should read Connectionstring from all the config files present inside a Folder(including Subfolders). I have developped win form App for this.

```
 private void btnConnString_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var files = Directory.GetFiles(
         this.txtPath.Text.Trim(), 
         "*.config", 
         SearchOption.AllDirectories);
     foreach (string filepath in files)
     {
         string fileName;
         fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
     } 
 }
```

Now I have to read connection string. How can I do?

Comment: What happened to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString....?

Comment: I'm thinking OP is looking to read config files not in their normal locations?  Not sure ConfigurationManager would handle that?

Comment: If there's nothing built-in to the framework for this, you could load each file into an XDocument and use LINQ to XML to get the connection strings really easily, assuming the config files are the standard .NET XML variety and not something custom.

Comment: @Tim I think ExeConfigurationFileMap class is just what he needs.

Answer (score 4):

You should try this approach:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = fileName;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
string connString =  config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"];
```

Hope Helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
            System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
        if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
        {
            connString =
                rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];
            if (connString != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = \"{0}\"",
                    connString.ConnectionString);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string");
        }
```

Comment: Nice example, except OP is writing a WinForm app, not a web app.

Answer (score 1):

```
string fileName;
fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);


MessageBox.Show(filepath);

ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = fileName;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];

if(connString!= null)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(connString.ConnectionString);
 }
else
   MessageBox.Show("No ConnectionString");
```

i have added this there is an entry in my connection strin still it is always taking null value

Comment: Please post your .config file. Anyway, try connString = config.AppSettings["ConnectionName"]

Answer (score 0):

```
class AppConfigurationReader
    {
        public List<string> key1;
        public List<string> key2;
        public int ConnectionStringsFound;

        public int GetTotalConnectionStringsFound()
        {
            ConnectionStringsFound = key1.Count();
            return (ConnectionStringsFound);
        }

        public AppConfigurationReader()
        {
            key1= new List<string>();
            key12 = new List<string>();

            ConnectionStringsFound = 0;
        }
        public void getAppConfigconnectionStrings(string webConfigPath)
        {
            DataTable dtKeyValue = new DataTable();

            dtKeyValue.TableName = "app.config connectionString";
            dtKeyValue.Columns.Add("name");
            dtKeyValue.Columns.Add("connectionString");

            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(webConfigPath);
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();

            XmlElement root = xdoc.DocumentElement;

            XmlNodeList appSettings = xdoc.SelectNodes("/configuration/connectionStrings/add");

            foreach (XmlNode node in appSettings)
            {
                DataRow row = dtKeyValue.NewRow();
                String name = node.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString();
                String connectionString = node.Attributes["connectionString"].Value.ToString();

                //row["name"] = name;
                //row["connectionString"] = connectionString;
                //dtKeyValue.Rows.Add(row);

                if (String.Equals(name, "Mykey1") == true)
                {
                    key1.Add(connectionString);
                }
                else if (String.Equals(name, "Mykey2") == true)
                {
                    key2.Add(connectionString);
                }
            }

            //return dtKeyValue;
        }
}
```